# Null Reference Exception querying data in EF6 after upgrading from EF4

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having some trouble getting data out of my entity framework context. I'm upgrading my application from entity framework 4 to 6 and it has not been a party.

Right now, if I try to query any records from my database I get a null reference exception.

```
DBSet<EntityObject> test1 = context.EntityObjects;
List<EntityObject> test2 = test1.ToList();
```

The first line runs without error. The second line throws a System.NullReferenceException with the following stack trace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.TypesMatchByConvention(Type type, EdmType cspaceType)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.TryCreateStructuralType(Type type, StructuralType cspaceType, EdmType& newOSpaceType)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.OSpaceTypeFactory.TryCreateType(Type type, EdmType cspaceType)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at ConnectServer.ConnectModule.handleReceive(Message message, ClientConnection client) in c:\Users\Eric Bowman\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NXConnect_ME578_Interoperability\CADInteroperabilityCATIA\ConnectServer\ConnectModule.cs:line 137
```

My closes guess right now is that there's a problem with my connection string which is preventing the context from connecting with the database, so here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <configSections>
         <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
         <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
         <add name="FancyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ConnectData.csdl|res://*/ConnectData.ssdl|res://*/ConnectData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost,1433;initial catalog=Fancy_Dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=************;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
         <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
         <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
         </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <startup>
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
```

Am I missing something in there? Could it be something else?

**UPDATE**

The connection string was bad, but even after fixing it I get exactly the same error. I can open a connection to the database, but when I try to look at any of the collections in the context, it throws a null reference exception.

This is very frustrating

**Another Update**

I haven't seen much help so I'm posting some of the information I've found.

I found the Entity Framework Source and this is the method that crashes:

```
    internal static bool TypesMatchByConvention(Type type, EdmType cspaceType)
    {
        return type.Name == cspaceType.Name;
    }
```

And here is the previous code block that calls the method:

```
        if (cspaceType.BaseType != null)
        {
            if (TypesMatchByConvention(type.BaseType, cspaceType.BaseType))
            {
                TrackClosure(type.BaseType);
                referenceResolutionListForCurrentType.Add(
                    () => ospaceType.BaseType = ResolveBaseType((StructuralType)cspaceType.BaseType, type));
            }
            else
            {
                var message = Strings.Validator_OSpace_Convention_BaseTypeIncompatible(
                    type.BaseType.FullName, type.FullName, cspaceType.BaseType.FullName);
                LogLoadMessage(message, cspaceType);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Note that it checks cspaceType.BaseType for null but not type.BaseType.

I created a fresh project with the same entity model and it works fine, so it's something to do with my specific settings or project or something.

Comment: I would look elsewhere for the problem first. A bad connection string should not give a NullReferenceException. You should get a timeout exception, or something more specific.

Comment: what is test variable? if you have not assigned to it a value maybe a null exception is what I would expect

Comment: none of the variables themselves are null, it happens somewhere in the entity framework classes. Look at the stack trace.

The test variable is a type-o from writing the post, I will fix it.

Comment: Not knowing your app but is the ToList() Method an extension Method you wrote, if so you may want it check there first.

Comment: the ToList() method is a linq extension method.

Thank you for the thoughts guys.

Comment: Not knowing the exact implementation details, my guess would be it's the fact that the EdmModel doesn't know your baseclass. Hence the type resolution of EntitySet<T> fails => null reference. Have you annotated your base class with your 'KnownType' derived classes? That might help.

Comment: When you upgraded to EF6 did you also upgrade the text template that's used to generate all the EF classes and regenerate everything?

Comment: yes, I did. I feel like there might be a clue in the stack trace. The surprising thing is how deep into entity framework the stack trace goes.

Comment: @Eric I want to put myself in context, do you use Migrations, "pre-generated views for Entity Framework", Code first, ...  ?

Comment: I actually deleted the EF 4 model completely and recreated it from scratch using the EF 6 tools.

I have created the model from scratch in another project and it works in that project, so maybe there's something left over in my main project?

Comment: @Eric What happens in TrackClosure(type.BaseType); AND what happens before if (cspaceType.BaseType != null) ???

Comment: To debug this problem I ended up not using the stack trace. I was trying to make a "non-proprietary" version of the solution that I could share and while I was removing stuff it suddenly started to work. So, I reverted my changes and started carefully removing code until it started to work. A few hours of detective work showed that code from a third party API that has classes with the same name caused the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a bad connections string when I posted this, so watch out for that but it wasn't actually the problem

the problem was a name conflict. One of my classes in Entity Framework had the same name as a class in one of my other references.

So, as a general practice I recommend giving each of your Entity Framework classes a prefix to make absolutely sure it's never the same as any class you might use in any library ever.

Comment: "in any library ever" This only is a problem with identical class names in the same assembly (but different namespaces).

Comment: I was referencing a third party API with classes of the same name. This caused a runtime nullreferenceexception.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find EntityObjects property anywhere in EF6 documentation. Are you sure you removed completely all references to EF4 from your project?

Maybe could you also replace your code by this:

```
EntityObject e = context.EntityObjects.FirstOrDefault();
```

And see what is the value of `e`?
Finally, if you're trying to select all objects from a table in your database and put them in a `List`, isn't this statement an option?

```
var myObjects = (from s in context.tableName select s).ToList();
```

Comment: EntityObject is the name of the base class for my entities

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem, where each time I called ToListAsync() on a DbSet EF threw a NullReferenceException. For the sake of anyone who ends up here from Google (I couldn't find any help online), in my case it was a mixup from calling async code synchronously (a restriction of an attribute from a third party framework).